# React native tap on touchable opacity while TextInput is focused

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm having a problem with React Native.

I have a TextInput, when focusing on the text input, I open a dropdown. Now, if I want to select something on the dropdown, I first have to click to lose the focus of the TextInput, and then it will capture the onPress event on the dropdown options.

I can manually for the blur when clicking on the textinput, but that way, the user won't be able to write on it.

Any solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Does your `TextInput` inside a `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this inside inside scrollView property

```
keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" so that it can be handled.
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I have the same problem but not in ScrollView. I click a "Sign In" button, while the focus is on "Password" TextInput with the Keyboard on. I want the button to be handled immediately and not after pressing 2 times (the 1st click just dismisses the keyboard)